# How to calculate number of years per country in R?

Tags: r

What is the easiest way to calculate the number of years per country in R? Please see the sample below.  **1)** How can I create the "#years" variable? The observation period in the real data is from 1990 to 2010, years are ordered ascendingly.

**2)** Also, would it be possible to start with "0", instead of "1"?

```
country year    #years
A       2000    1
A       2001    2
A       2002    3
B       2000    1
B       2001    2
B       2002    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `ave` from `base R`

```
years <- with(df1, ave(year, country, FUN=seq_along))
```

If we need to start from 0

```
years <- years -1
df1$years <- years
```

---

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, years := seq_len(.N), country]
```